# The definition of Macro

Tags: ios, objective-c

A simple question related to the definition of Macro:

[image]

How to fix it , thks~

Comment: #if is a preprocessor directive that you are feeding code.  The preprocessor does not evaluate statements, it just pastes tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the block with following Macro just to turn that error off:

`#define MBLabelAlignmentCenter  __SYSTEM_VERSION_IT >= 7.0 ? NSTextAlignmentCenter : UITextAlignmentCenter`

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor conditional macros only accept compile-time constant expressions. Your #define part that can be resolved at compile time. An #if only works if the conditional is something that can be determined at compile time. It cannot be used to change behavior at runtime based on the environment an app is running on.

2 way to resolve:

```
#define MBLabelAlignmentCenter  __SYSTEM_VERSION_IT >= 7.0 ? NSTextAlignmentCenter : UITextAlignmentCenter
```

Or use plain if else code:

```
if(__SYSTEM_VERSION_IT >= 7.0)
{
    MBLabelAlignmentCenter = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
else{
    MBLabelAlignmentCenter = UITextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)